# Dynamics 365 ssrs create multiple report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I want to create a multiple page invoice report with ssrs. 
I need to show one picture at first page and after that show parent and then show child rdl. 
I try every thing but in Microsoft CRM i have only two option, i can create single page report and a parent child report there is no option to create a three or four page report.

please help me to create a report that show a static Picture at first page and then show main report that have a parent and a child?

Comment: You are using the CRM Report Wizard tool? I think to have custom page breaks you need to download the Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) extension and prepare your report in Visual Studio

Comment: No I Use BI (Sql Data Tools) For generating Reports.

Answer (score 1):

Is your image dynamic or static?

For a static image, add an image control at the top of the report, in the body. Then, add a page break. The option should be on the control under the image. Like a tablix.

[image]

[image]